# Could someone tell me what is the difference between a class and a structure in c++

Tags: c++, class, struct

For example, what is the difference between:

```
strucut Nodo{
    Nodo *siguiente,*anterior;
    char* Nombre,Curso;
    long,carnet;
    Nodo(){
        siguiente=anterior=NULL;
    }
```

and:

```
class Nodo{
public:    
Nodo *siguiente,*anterior;
char* Nombre,Curso;
long carnet;
Nodo(){
    siguiente=anterior=NULL;
    }
```

A difference that i think i saw was that in class you must put public, or in other hand all the statements will be private, but i can´t see any important difference, or any crusial difference. There are some important aspect that i dont know?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only difference between a `class` and a `struct` is the default access specifier. A `class`'s members are `private` by default, whereas a `struct`'s members are `public` by default. This also means that `class` inheritance is `private` by default and `struct` inheritance is `public` by default.

As described by the standard:

> Members of a class defined with the keyword `class` are `private` by default. Members of a class defined with the keywords `struct` or `union` are `public` by default.

And for inheritance:

> In the absence of an *access-specifier* for a base class, `public` is assumed when the derived class is defined with the *class-key* `struct` and `private` is assumed when the class is defined with the *class-key* `class`.